# Network analysis and adjacency matrices

Tags: python, vba, arcgis, esri, arcmap

I want to try and create a network for several hundred shapefiles that consist of polylines. The polylines are snapped to each other and consistent. Then I want to create an adjacency matrix for this network.

What is the best way of doing this? I know how to do it on an individual basis by clicking through options within [ArcCatalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcCatalog), but I want to try and explore how to automate this.

I do have some VBA that I previously downloaded that creates an adjacency matrix once I have made the network, but I can only run that once the network is loaded in to [ArcMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcMap), with the layers in a specific order.

I appreciate any suggestion or advice about how to do this, in any language. I know this is quite a program specific question; and I have asked it on the ESRI forum too, but my previous questions did not results in an answer that enabled me to achieve this so I thought I would also ask it here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve but when it comes to network analysis in python take a look at [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/).